# Image not appearing in Gallery

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using this code to take the picture from the camera

```
Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);   
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/Camera/"); 

if(!storagePath.isDirectory()){   
  storagePath.mkdirs(); 
}

File myImage = new File(storagePath,
Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"); 
Uri fromURI=Uri.fromFile(myImage); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fromURI);
startActivityForResult(intent,PulseConstants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The image is stored correctly with the given file name in "My Files" folder of the phone...But when I open Gallery of the phone, this image does not appear ??

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong??

TIA,
VijayRaj

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with the fact that the Android media scanner is not constantly indexing files on the phone. In the past I have called the following function immediately after saving an image to notify the MediaScanner:

```
private void scanMedia(File file) {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
        sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
}
```

Hope this works!